# Poping up a custom mail chimp form

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, popup, bpopup

I want to pop up a custom designed mail chimp form, like Groupon/Fab etc do upon page load. I have copied the code of the form and now have it as a page on our server, however I am having no luck creating a pop up of the page/form on page load. I have tried shadowbox, bpopup and others with no luck. I can get it to "pop up" on a button push, but the pop up essentially just loads the whole form page instead of raising the port page up, centering it and dimming and locking the background. jquery is not my strong suit so any help would be greatly appreciated. Also, I am not wedded to jquery so if something else like ajax would be quicker for this application than great.

Answer (score 0):

I would try something w/ jQuery's ready() function.  http://api.jquery.com/ready/